# Is there a way to show certain rows of a code file in Latex?

Tags: latex

So what I want to do is close to this e.g code
\lstinputlisting[language=Octave]{BitXorMatrix.m}
but lets say that the file 120 rows long and i only want to include row 12-19 in my document, is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings)' `linerange` key-value will do this. See [Using `\lstinputlisting` to include a file but only certain lines or line ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34323/5764)

Answer (score 1):

```
 \lstinputlisting[language=Octave,linerange={12-19}]{BitXorMatrix.m}
```

or

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Octave,firstline=12,lastline=19]{BitXorMatrix.m}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who wanted to know this for minted, it is:

```
\inputminted[firstline=27,lastline=31]{source.txt}
```